# How to integrate on an arbitary quadrilateral?

Tags: integration, quadrilateral

Suppose there is a function f(x,y,z) and we have a quadrilateral in the space. How to integrate f(x,y,z) on the quadrilateral? I have tried to divide the quadrilateral into two triangles, but could anyone please tell me how to integrate on the triangles? Is there a simple method for this problem?

Comment: Why not apply a linear transformation to make the quadrilateral a square and use Fubinis theorem and the change of variables formula. You will of course need f to be measurable in the product measure.

Comment: @user54092  Because the quadrilateral is arbitary, sometimes, we can't find a linear transfornation to transform the quadrilateral to a square.

Comment: Today I learned what I quadrilateral is. :)

Comment: Warning. In the space a quadrilateral is not necessarily plane and can be "incurvé" (French), "alabeado" (Spanish) ("curved", "warped" in English?). Maybe you're asking only for flat quadrilaterals  and if so, then it should be clarified.

Comment: For 2D polynomials F(x,y), here's an exact solution: https://users.cs.northwestern.edu/~jet/docs/2006JGT_MatrixVol04_18.pdf (my 2004 paper for Journal of Graphics Tools)
-Jack Tumblin